# PCIe slot #2 no detecting gpu on (2nd) brand new Gigabyte G1 x99 Gaming wifi

Tags: motherboard, pci-express

I'm losing my mind over this, but here goes. Brand new Gigabyte G1 X99 Gaming Wifi mobo, New i7-5820k cpu, new Corsair Vengeance 16gb (4gbx4) 2800 ram with New OCZ Vertex SSD 120gb.

So upon install, My 2nd GPU (EVGA GTX 580s) wasn't being detected. The motherboard was revision 1, and had the F4 bios. Thought the issue was me running Windows 10 tech preview, so I switched back to my Windows 7 pro. Still no luck. Tested both cards in slot #1 solo and both  worked. Then tested both cards in Slot 1 and 4, both detected together and sli is an option. Slot 3 works with my 9500gt. Tried again with slot 1 and 2, slot 2 detects nothing. All drivers removed, wiped with driversweeper, and reinstalled. Nothing.

Next I tried to update the bios. Couldn't sworn I saw an F8, but had no luck installing (bad image) so went with F7 and flashed fine. Reinstalled the OS (win7) and nothing. Poked around the bios, but only thing I saw (unless I missed something) was setting pcie from auto to gen 1,2,3. Set the bios to use pcie 2 as the display output.. but never got a signal. Wiped, tried again, got frustrated and guessed a defect. RMA'd it the next day to Newegg, who sent a new board.

Guessing they never even tested it, because I just got my new one, and same issue. Same troubleshooting steps and I simply can't get the second slot to work. The manual says that slot #3 is disabled with a 5820k, and that slot #4 should only be used for 3 way sli, and specifically states to use slot #1 and #2 for two way sli, for any cpu. I'm at a loss. I now have 3 GPU's up and running, in slots 1, 3 and 4. But slot 2 still detects nothing. Maybe someone has some troubleshooting steps to try and some other advice? I'm pretty sure it isn't hardware, as it's the second mobo, and both cards work fine when I toss em back into my x58 board, and even tested my 9500gt just to be sure.

Comment: Have you tested with just one card in slot 2 and no cards in the other slots? If the slot doesn't work when you try it alone then it is likely broken.

Comment: I did try, and no go.. however I tried that on the first board.. then RMA'd it, and was sent another new one. Have a hard time believing I received two knew boards with the same damaged slot.

Comment: I have the same board and have the same issue as you with my 2 x GTS 250's i have them in slot 1 and 4 so at least i can use them as separate cards but when using slot 1 and 2 the card in 2 will not recognize. The problem is that if you want to run SLI they need to be in 1 and 2. its good to know i am not the only one, so it must be a bug or compatibility issue with our older GPU's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. 
Not sure exactly what was the cause but likely the bios update to F8
I was on F5 so I am not sure which Update it was that fixed it. All I did was I loaded the 2 gpu's in slot 1 and 2 with the SLI connector then I did the BIOS update to F8. On loading of Windows and it did take a while for windows to load some configurations. Now my GPU runs in slot 2.

Now my last item which shouldn't be to bad is getting Windows to recognize these cards as running in 2way SLI.

Tried uninstalling drivers and reinstalling drivers. Using add remove programs. Thinking I may need to remove the drivers from the Device Manager then reload them. Windows always reloads the drivers on restart so I don't think it is getting a fresh driver install and from what I read thats what is needed to get SLI going and have the Control Panel finally give me that option.

Comment: This is it.. right here! I finally decided to check back, as I'd all but given up. I updated the bios (F9 for me, as thats the current) and hot-diggidy-daffodil, card was recognized! Gotta resetup the layout of sli and monitors, but glad to have full speed sli.. plus it looks nicer in the case :)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you (like me) assumed that the PCIe slots were numbered from 1 to 4 like so:

```
1. PCIe
2. PCIe
3. PCIe
4. PCIe
```

The problem is that they are not. according to the manual they are numbered like so:

```
1. PCIe
4. PCIe
2. PCIe
3. PCIe
```

So you were actually trying to use the first and fourth slot. The manual states that for two way SLI with an i7-5820K CPU the first and second slot should be used. Like so:

```
1. PCIe <-- this one
4. PCIe
2. PCIe <-- and this one
3. PCIe
```

Here is a link to the manual: [Manual](http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-x99-gaming-g1-wifi_e.pdf)

Information about SLI / Crossfire can be found on page 19.

Please inform and forgive me if the assumptions that I have made are incorrect.

I hope this helps. Have a nice day.

Comment: Common mistake I'm sure, but not the case here. http://i.imgur.com/LfgXZtd.jpg Cards are in the right slots.. and slot #3 will detect my 9500gt. Second board to do this on arrival so I'm doubting the board is physically damaged.